# I have a question about Time taken based on different rates working together

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's the question:
Jim can fill a pool with water by the bucket in 30 minutes. Sue can do the same job in 45 minutes. Tony can do the same job in 90 minutes. How quickly can all three fill the pool together?

I just need verification. I came up with 15 minutes. To make it simple I've assumed it takes 30 buckets to fill the pool. So, Jim does 1/min, Sue does .67/min, and Tony does .33/min. Together is a total of 2/min, meaning to get to 30 buckets it would take 15 minutes. The answer key on this sample test says the answer is 23 minutes. Please confirm the book is full of it

Comment: Book is full of it. Your math would have been a little easier using 90 buckets = 1 pool and avoiding the fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.
The way I would look at it would be to say that Jim fills at 1/30 pools/minute, Sue fills at 1/45 pools/minute and Tony fills at 1/90 pools/min. So all three will fill at 1/30+1/45+1/90=1/15 pools/minute. Invert the latter to show that it will take 15 minutes to fill 1 pool.